# Workflow for Field Update

Tags: workflow

Because my Multi-Select field hits the 5K or 3,900 Limit of SFDC. I have arrived at this thing. I split the big formula (Hard-Coded) into two fields (Field_B & Field_C).
I have this Scenario :
Two Objects : "Application" & "Contact"
I want to Update a Formula field "(Field_A = Field_B + Field_C)" in "Application" object when there is a change in fields "(Field_D)" of "Contact" Object. A look-up relationship exists between both the objects.

So i want to achieve this Using Workflow rule written on "Application".
Something like this should happen Field_A = Field_B + Field_C.

I know there is an alternative for Trigger for Cross-object field Updation. But i would like to achieve this using WFR.

Comment: Try using Process builder

Comment: If the relationship is master detail then you can update parent side in workflow...otherwise use Process Builder or trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using "Tips for Reducing Formula Size" pdf knowledge article. Working fine for me using Workflow rule and cross updation!

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to go that way. When picklists or multi-select get too big the best thing to do is to replace them with custom objects. A very simple design will help you achieve what you need.

Assuming the object with your long multi pick list is A

- create a new custom object (B) that contains all the options as individual records.
- create a new custom object (C) with two master-details relationships: one to A and one to B.

I hope it helps.